# Join query on Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

HI
I have following tables

```
=========================
Periods
=========================
PeriodID  StartDate   EndDate
1         01-01-11    07-01-11
2         08-01-11    15-01-11
```

and so on for whole year

```
=========================
History
=========================
PersonID  From       To
1         01-01-11  05-04-11
2         17-06-11   NULL 
and so on
```

I want the following output

```
 StartDate   EndDate   PersonID
  01-01-11    07-01-11    1
  08-01-11    15-01-11    1
  .
  .
  15-04-11   21-04-11     NULL
  .
  .
  15-06-11   21-06-11     2
```

I need to take  join between these two tables but i couldn't figure how join condition will be look like

Ragards

Comment: IS History a Many to Many relationship to User table?

Comment: @ysrb for one period there will be only one person at one time

Comment: OK let me try it. one more thing  In history table start date and end dates are not necessarily matching from period table i.e. these dates may be any date of year

Comment: If the period start and end dates don't match the person from and to dates, what logic should be used to match the person records with the period records?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.StartDate,
  p.EndDate,
  h.PersonID
FROM Periods p
  LEFT JOIN History h
    ON h.[From] BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate OR
       p.StartDate BETWEEN h.[From] AND ISNULL(h.[To], '30000101')
```

Answer (score 2):

It would affect performance, but I think it is worth just trying the odd looking between:

```
select x
from table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2
    on t2.date between t1.startdate and t1.enddate
```

Whether it works or not will depend on whether this is to be production, or just a one time thing, and how many records are involved. It may be way too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try:

```
SELECT P.StartDate, P.EndDate, H.PersonID
FROM Period P INNER JOIN History H ON P.StartDate <= H.Fromand (P.EndDate >= H.To OR H.To IS NULL)
```

I have edited the SQL after reading the spec more clearly

I have edited the SQL again. I'm using INNER JOIN now.

Comment: it can't be an inner join because it needs to show the period even if there are no history entries for that period (look at line 5 of the output)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a left join in order to show all the periods available even if there are no history entries associated with that period. The criteria would be if the History date was between the period. You would also need to check if the To date was null and include it into your results

```
SELECT  p.StartDate, p.EndDate, h.PersonId
FROM    Period p
        LEFT JOIN History h
            ON p.StartDate >= h.[From] AND 
            (h.[To] IS NULL OR p.EndDate <= h.[To])
```

Comment: The output is returning all records from period as expected it is showing personid =1 correctly but where personID =2 should be shown it is showing null

Comment: p.EndDate IS NULL should be h.EndDate Am I right?. When i change that I miss one period which is in the range of 17-06-11

Comment: @Tassadaque I had a typo in there. it should not have been checking for the p.EndDate being null but should have been checking if the h.[To] column was null.

Answer (score -1):

at table `history`, set `NULL` to `9999-12-31`

```
SELECT *
FROM periods a
INNER JOIN history b
ON a.FROM < b.TO AND a.TO > b.FROM
```

Comment: No!!! This is a very ugly, non-portable hack. Explicitely test for `NULL` instead.